How to stop Liferay login portlet opening in maximize state in case of error?
I've placed login portlet in a content page in two column grid and applied some style and content. But when user save it with invalid authentication, It opens in maximize state. Is there any workaround to prevent this situation?
Thanks in advance

The way we mostly do it is to create an MVCActionCommand and override the WindowState manually.
Below, you can find a piece of code that will do this.
@Component(
        immediate = true,
        property = {
                "javax.portlet.name=" + LoginPortletKeys.LOGIN,
                "javax.portlet.name=" + LoginPortletKeys.FAST_LOGIN,
                "mvc.command.name=/login/login",
                "service.ranking:Integer=300"
        },
        service = MVCActionCommand.class
)
public class CustomLoginMVCActionCommand implements MVCActionCommand {

    @Reference(target = "(component.name=com.liferay.login.web.internal.portlet.action.LoginMVCActionCommand)")
    protected MVCActionCommand mvcActionCommand;

    @Override
    public boolean processAction(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) throws PortletException {
        ...

        mvcActionCommand.processAction(actionRequest, actionResponse);

        actionResponse.setWindowState(WindowState.NORMAL);

        return true;
    }
}

